# How to different Permission give in User Marketing,Sale,Accounting in magento?

Tags: magento-1.9, permissions, user-roles

My question is permission Roles.

1. Marketing user access only in Rating of Vender,Dashboard,Promotion
   etc.
2. Sale Manger user access only in order,shipment,status,Product
   edit/delete/ etc..
3. Accounting user access only  in payment,Vender
   Dashboard,Credit memo...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Magento have a great functionally which called **ACL(Access Control Lists)**.

By using you can  define different permission for different user using their roles.

In role, you can restrict permission areas for a user.

Role can set at  **System menu>Permissions>Roles** section.

[image]

You can get more details  about ACL Setting at

- [Alam Storm blog](http://alanstorm.com/magento_acl_authentication)
- [Hostknox](http://www.hostknox.com/tutorials/magento/users-and-user-roles)